# How to call this route un Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I Made a scaffold and Made the class "project".
This make in routes.rb the resources.
I make another route

```
Get 'projects/status/:id', to 'projects#status'
```

How can i call this link on the HTML code?
I tried

```
<%= link_to "show status", '/status'project.id %>
```

But it doesn't work.
Please help

Comment: I'd recommend you to first try your endpoint out with an API testing tools like Postman. Once you know that it's working correctly, then integrate it in your erb file. For your erb you'll probably want <%=link_to "Show status", status_path(@project.id)%>

Comment: running `rails routes` in terminal will list all your current routes including the prefix for your route. You may include that in the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link to the path you defined use plain string with interpolation for `:id` parameter

```
# GET /projects/status/:id

# config/routes.rb
get 'projects/status/:id', to: 'projects#status'

# view
<%= link_to 'status', "/projects/status/#{@project.id}" %>
```

You can add a path helper method by using `:as` option. It is also better to append `status` path to keep it consistent with rails conventions and to not clash with `:id` param. This is similar to other `project` routes, like `edit` and `new`. Now you have `status` route for your project.

```
# project_status GET /projects/:id/status

# config/routes.rb
# NOTE: `as: :project_status` will create `project_status_path` and `project_status_url` helpers
get 'projects/:id/status', to: 'projects#status', as: :project_status

# view
# NOTE: path helper will automatically extract `:id` param from @project
<%= link_to 'status', project_status_path(@project) %>
```

Route can be nested under project resources. For all options see:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.2.3/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match

```
# status_project GET /projects/:id/status

# config/routes.rb
resources :projects do
  get :status, on: :member
end

# view
<%= link_to 'status', status_project_path(@project) %>

# TODO: maybe fix backwards helper name
# get :status, on: :member, as: :state_of
# => state_of_project_path(@project)
```

To see your routes

```
bin/rails routes
# helper name         # url                              # controller#action
project_status GET    /projects/:id/status(.:format)     projects#status
```